# Socket is closed Exception when trying sslException

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am trying to implement a SSL connection using a custom certificate on an Android client. If i try to connect to the same Server using a normal Java program I wrote (where I import the keystore using system parameters) everything works fine. Also if I connect to the server using the android method, but without https it works fine. But once I use the Android method with https (with the method shown below) it gives me this Error:

```
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.checkOpen(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:237)
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:250)
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
04-06 20:12:29.234: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at john.z.lead.utils.ServerRequest.get_response(ServerRequest.java:497)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at john.z.lead.utils.ServerRequest.logout(ServerRequest.java:797)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at john.z.lead.fragments.Logout_Fragment$1$1.run(Logout_Fragment.java:59)
04-06 20:12:29.244: W/System.err(2328):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

the code I am using is:

```
public static JSONObject get_response(List<Parameter> params,
        final String address) throws IOException, JSONException, LeadException {
    // String body = "param1=" + URLEncoder.encode( "value1", "UTF-8" ) +
    // "&" +
    // "param2=" + URLEncoder.encode( "value2", "UTF-8" );

    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    for (Parameter pa : params) {
        body.append(pa.getKey() + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(pa.getValue(), "UTF-8") + "&");
    }
    try {

        URL url = new URL(address);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = Datastore.getActiv().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
            // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted
            // certificates
            // Also provide the password of the keystore
            trusted.load(in, "lead".toCharArray());

            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(trusted);



            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);


            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection)
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        }
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                String.valueOf(body.length()));
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(body.toString());
        writer.flush();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            build.append(line);
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();

        return new JSONObject(build.toString());

    } catch (UnknownHostException | FileNotFoundException
            | ConnectException e) {
        Datastore.getActiv().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(
                        Datastore.getActiv(),
                        "Konnte keine Verbindung zum Server ( "
                                + address
                                + " ) herstellen.\nBitte überprüfen Sie ihre Netzwerkverbindung und / oder\nkontaktieren Sie einen Administrator",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ;

            }

        });
        throw e;
    } catch (KeyManagementException|KeyStoreException|NoSuchAlgorithmException|CertificateException e) {
        MessageDialog.showMessageDialog(Datastore.getActiv(), "Es ist ein kritischer Fehler beim Herstellen der sicheren Verbindung aufgetreten");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new LeadException(LeadException.Errorcode.UNKNOWN);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SocketException: socket is closed` means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it.

NB You don't need to set the `Content-Length` header. `HttpURLConnection` does that automatically for you.

Comment: But i never closed the socket. This error must result from something inside the if-block, because if the url is non-https the error does not occur